# Creating Folder and Insert file in Moodle

Tags: php, file, api, directory, moodle

I have a problem. I was working with Moodle and Multiagent systems, but now, the new version of moodle denied me to create folders and add files to it using only the database.

Can someone help me with this? I have to use moodle API in PHP to do it. can you guys help me?

Comment: What do you want to do with the file - Is it available system wide or for a course or for a user? How is the file uploaded? Via a form or externally?

Comment: externally, after file upload, I used to insert the path in Moodle's Database, and moodle used to show it there, but now, moodle doesn't show, and I did read about and saw that I have to use PHP Moodle API.

Answer (score 0):

You could try file system repository - you can set up a folder in the dataroot for incoming uploads - then go into Moodle to assign the file to a course.

https://docs.moodle.org/26/en/File_system_repository

Comment: I was talking about to create a folder module on Moodle, like Wiki, Chat, we have Folder